# Scores of deleted comments appear partially outside background area on iOS

Tags: bug, comments, design, moderator-tools, ios

Moderators have a button which allows them to view deleted comments underneath a post. In Safari on iOS (both iPad and iPhone), scores of these comments appear partially outside the red background area:

[image]

On my desktop browsers everything looks fine.

Comment: Nice userscript you got there. I recognise that comment section, and I'm pretty sure I remember at least who "user1" and "user3" are.

Comment: @Randal'Thor that doesn't surprise me :) I'm not sure if the anonymization was necessary, the comments are harmless, but at least I've tried ...

Comment: HAH I'm looking at your pink screenshot and thinking "why can I see deleted comments here?"